# HTML - Sidebar not closing when clicking outside of it

Tags: javascript, html, css, sidebar

I have a sidebar that shows when an image is pressed. However, when I click outside of the sidebar, any area that is not the sidebar, it doesn't close. I tried looking it up but I didn't find a solution.

I am not so familiar with html so this might just be an easy fix.

```js
var side = document.getElementById('mySidenav');
sideBarOpen = false;

function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "300px";
  document.getElementById("arrow").style.transform = "rotate(90deg)";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";

  sideBarOpen = true;
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
  document.getElementById("arrow").style.transform = "rotate(0deg)";
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  sideBarOpen = false;
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (sideBarOpen) {
    if (!event.target == side) {
      closeNav();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#"><img src="clubsIcon.svg" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" align="center"></a>
  <a href="#"> &#8594;  <img src="srIcon.svg" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" align="center"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="cricketIcon.svg" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" align="center"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="fblaIcon.svg" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" align="center"></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="roboticsIcon.svg" style="width: 30px; height: 30px;" align="center"></a>
</div>

<div style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">
  <img src="arrow.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" id="arrow" class="arrowclass">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line in your code that is wrong is this:

```
if (!event.target == side) {
```

as `!event.target` will return a boolean which you are then comparing to an element. So you'll always get a negative response from this comparison.

it should be:

```
if (event.target !== side) {
```

Once that is sorted out, you will also have a logic problem as the opener button is positioned outside of the sidebar.  You need to add a check that the window click event is not coming from the opener button in addition to your existing check that it isn't coming from the sidebar. See code changes below:

```
<div  id="openIcon" style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">
  <img src="arrow.png" style="width: 20px; height: 20px;" id="arrow" class="arrowclass">
</div>
```

javscript:

```
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (sideBarOpen) {
    if (event.target !== side && event.target !== document.getElementById('openIcon')) {
      closeNav();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I made the necessary changes listed above. However, I cannot open the sidebar by click on the arrow. The only way I can do so is by clicking anything besides from the arrow, such as to the right of it.

Comment: Nevermind I got it to work. Instead of testing to see if event.target is not in the div, I make sure that it is not clicking on the arrow. Changed it to the arrow id.

Comment: Can you take a look at my problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51165775/gif-images-being-loaded-in-weird-position-on-chrome   I would really appreciate it.